# Dynamically adding content to the website

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website, and on the main page, there is a form to create div's on that same page. The form has entries of name of the div, color of the div, coordinates of the upper left corner of the div (for example, the entry can be [50 70]) and the coordinates of the lower right corner of the div (for example, the entry can be [780 800]). I need the code that will enable me to dynamically create div's on the page with the specified parameters, so I don't have to edit the source code myself - so that the user can come in, fill out a form, and the div to be created. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you have to use javascript (no way around that) and implement a handler for some event, probably a click event on a "create" button or similar. That handler functions reads the values from the form and creates an element and inserts it into the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around by understanding this code.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="value" id='value' />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="createDiv()" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
function createDiv() {
        var divName = document.getElementById('value').value; //getting value for div name
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div'); //creating div element
        iDiv.name = divName;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv) //adding it in DOM tree
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try these out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
function CreateDiv() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
  var ulcorner = document.getElementById('ulcorner').value;
  var brcorner = document.getElementById('brcorner').value;
  
  var top    = parseInt(ulcorner.split(',')[0]);
  var left   = parseInt(ulcorner.split(',')[1]);
  var bottom = parseInt(brcorner.split(',')[0]);
  var right  = parseInt(brcorner.split(',')[1]);

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
  newDiv.style.top = top + 'px';
  newDiv.style.left = left + 'px';
  newDiv.style.height = (top + bottom) + 'px';
  newDiv.style.width = (left + right) + 'px';
  
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```html
Name :  <input type='text' id='name' /><br />
Color : <input type='text' id='color' /><br />
Coordinates of the upper left corner : 
<input type='text' id='ulcorner' placeholder='xx,xx' /><br />
Coordinates of the lower right corner : 
<input type='text' id='brcorner' placeholder='xx,xx' /><br />
<button onclick='CreateDiv()'>Create Div</button>
  
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try these solutions out yet, but I will do it soon - that's when I will mark the answer. Thanks.

Comment: But the div's that are created with this method disappear after I leave the page - the whole idea is to have the div's persist, so that if the user creates a div, leaves the page and then comes back to it, or if someone else visits the page, the div should still be there.